# Extension for browser to copy page source code to clipboard

Tags: browser, clipboard

I'm looking for browser extension that can quickly copy page source code to clipboard. (For example, just click button and all copied).

Answer (score 1):

Is next combination is not quick? (considering you are in FF)

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +<kbd>U</kbd> open source code pop-up

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> select all

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> copy to clipboard

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd> close source code pop-up

**UPDATE**

Also look at [this](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/extended-copy-menu/) plugin

Comment: When you need copy from hundreds of pages it is not quick.

Comment: @Tuco quick google point me to the plugin that i added to my answer

Answer (score 0):

[This extension](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/mpiodijhokgodhhofbcjdecpffjipkle) doesn't copy the real source code but it download the page in a single file with the source code modified a little bit (hehe)...